# What are the limitations or downsides of using Procedural Textures extensively?

Tags: textures, procedural-generation, optimization, unreal-5

Are there negative consequences to making heavy use of 'procedurally generated textures' in Unreal Engine 5, as opposed to normal textures? I found some info in the docs that it 'saves memory', but couldn't find any negatives.

I'm thinking of a large scene, like a city street, with procedural textures for its walls and floors, along with all the props, vehicles, NPCs and everything else.

Will there be issues such as lag, hitching, slow loading times, or any other negative complications when it comes to playing (on a laptop/PC of 'average' specs, not a gaming PC)?